# Implementing Rails Dynamic Partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, partials

I was building out a CMS and ran into trouble in implementing a new feature. Essentially, I aim to have a user own several locations that exist in a menu, and as a 'User' clicks on each one of the 'Locations', the partial on that page then displays all the 'Signs' that belong_to that 'Location' and only those 'Signs' that belong_to that 'Location'. The data model is very straight forward as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :restaurants, dependent: :destroy
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    validates  :user_id, presence: true

    has_many :campaigns, dependent: :destroy
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

In terms of implementation however, I am unaware of how to make the partials in the page dependent on what the user has selected and then display only that associated content.

At present I have the `show` for the users as:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                <%= gravatar_for @user %>
                <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>
        </section>
        <section>
            <% if @user.locations.any? %>
                <div>
                    <%= link_to "Start a Campaign", newcampaign_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
                </div>
                <%= link_to "Manage Locations", uploadlocations_path %>     
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to "Upload Locations", uploadlocations_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %> 
            <% end %>
        </section>
        <section>

            <%# disply list of restaurants%>

            <%= link_to "Add New Restaurant", newrestaurant_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
            <ul class ="campaigns">
                <%= render @restaurants %>
            </ul>

        </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
        <% if @restaurants.any? %>

            <ol class="campaigns">
                <%= render @campaigns, object: @restaurants %>
            </ol>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the user able to click on the specific restaurant in the side menu at `render @restaurants`, which goes to the partial:

```
<ul>
    <span class="content">
        <%= link_to restaurant.name, '#' %>
    </class>
</ul>
```

How can I have a user click on a restaurant in the menu and send that specific restaurant selected back into the `<%= render @campaigns, object: @restaurants %>` in the users `show` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possibe way after having slected a user is

```
@restaurants = @user.restaurants
```

is this what you are thinking of

```
@campaigns = @restaurant.campaigns
```

Comment: I am to have multi level access, ie. you select the restaurant and it shows all the campaigns. How can that be implemented?

Comment: @campaigns = @restaurant.campaigns?

Comment: yes, but how can I get the restaurant that the user selected back to the view? I updated the question